# My docker does not recognise existing nodes and topics

Tags: ros2, docker

I’m using wsl to run a docker with arm64 platform in order to compile the packages that will go on a debix model A board.
My problem is that sometimes I want to test the packages I have but when I launch any run the same docker does not recognize any node or topic.
My command:
“wsl -d ubuntu docker run --network=my-net -it --rm --platform linux/arm64 -v /mnt/c/dev/:/home ros:humble”

[image: image image 1109×256 13.7 KB]
In the following image you can see how the talkerdoes not show topic or node (it is difficult to see because it is in the background)

[image: image image 1098×312 14.7 KB]
In the future I would like to have wsl to use docker for anything (gazebo, rviz, node testing) always keeping wsl as clean as possible, if I couldn’t do everything through docker then it would be all with wls. I have seen that there are dockers for gazebo[https://hub.docker.com/_/gazebo] and also people who have managed to use gazebo in wsl and can see it as if it was a windows program[https://discourse.ros.org/t/linux-gui-added-to-wsl/20007/5].

UPDATE: I have found many people using an osrf docker image, with this docker image I can see the themes and nodes. Does anyone know why it works with the osrf docker image but not with the official ros docker image?